# In Java, is there any way to alias an object field so that it has two names?

Tags: java, spring-boot, annotations, lombok

I'm getting back into Java programming, and I have a situation where I'd like to do something like this:

```
public class FieldAliasTest {
    
    static public class Something {
        @Alias("somethingId")
        public Long id;
        @Alias("id")
        public Long somethingId;
    }
    
    static public void main(String[]args) {
        Something mySomething = new Something();
        mySomething.id = 1L;
        assert(mySomething.somethingId == 1L);
        mySomething.somethingId = 2L;
        assert(mySomething.id == 2L);
    }
}
```

Is there anything in the Java standard, Spring Boot, and/or Lombok libraries that would make that possible?

Is it possible at all?

I'm trying to avoid adding any functions like setSomethingId() and setId().

Comment: write 2 methods that returns the same variable

Comment: Yes, that's an obvious solution, but in this case I'd rather not do that... I'd rather it look exactly like two fields but really be one. (Or be two fields with "triggers" so that when one is updated, the other is also.)

Comment: I can't think of a use-case for 2 mirrored attributes in a same class

Comment: These are auto-generated classes from a database schema. They're more like structs (but Lombok Getters and Setters are being generated). The library requires that the field name match the column name in "snake case": "somethingId" matches "something_id" in the table. I'd like to treat them all generically as if every primary key were just named "id". I'm declaring abstract setId() and getId() functions in the interface and implementing them. It works, but I wondered if it were possible to make them look like instance variables such that the Lombok-generated get and set would work.

Comment: I know the Jackson library has something similar but for serialization to JSON (https://www.concretepage.com/jackson-api/jackson-jsonproperty-and-jsonalias-example#JsonAlias) not sure if that's of help

Comment: If these classes are generated, you'll probably lose any changes you make right?  Creating getters and setters that match your preferred spec does in fact effectively create the alias.  In your example, create a `getSomethingId` and `setSomethingId` methods and viola, you have a `somethingId` property (at least as far as any consumers go).

Comment: Or, what about `@AliasFor` (https://www.baeldung.com/spring-aliasfor-annotation) does that help your case? - I have not used it myself but it looks promising

Comment: I looked at `@AliasFor`, but that seems to be only for defining annotations. @lane.maxwell: good point: adding the alias field breaks the auto-generated aspect. I guess I'm just too fond of the `@Getter` and `@Setter` annotations. :-) I've gotten to the point where I hate seeing getX() and setX(X).

Answer (score 2):

In short, no.  Java does not support this.

You can build something like this, noting that you define aliases per instance, not on the class itself.  Modify as needed:

```java
public class AliasThingy {
    private final Map<String, Object> storage = new HashMap<>();
    private final Map<String, String> aliases = new HashMap<>();

    public AliasThingy (Map<String, List<String>> aliases) {
        aliases.forEach((key, value) -> value.forEach(alias -> this.aliases.put(alias, key)));
    }

    public void set(String key, Object value) {
        storage.put(aliases.getOrDefault(key, key), value);
    }

    public <T> T get(String key) {
        return (T)storage.get(aliases.getOrDefault(key, key));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var something = new AliasThingy(Map.of(
            "id", List.of("somethingId")
        ));
        something.set("id", 1L);
        assert((long)something.get("somethingId") == 1L);

        something.set("somethingId", 2L);
        assert((long)something.get("id") == 2L);
    }
}
```

You could also use it as a base class, which lets you define the aliases in the class definition, plus an opportunity to avoid raw strings:

```java
public class Something extends AliasThingy {
    public interface KEYS {
        String ID = "id";
        String SOMETHING_ID = "somethingId";
        String NAME = "name";
        String DESCRIPTION = "description";
        String TITLE = "title";
    }
    public Something() {
        super(Map.of(
            KEYS.ID, List.of(KEYS.SOMETHING_ID),
            KEYS.NAME, List.of(KEYS.DESCRIPTION, KEYS.TITLE)
        ));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Something something = new Something();
        something.set(KEYS.ID, 1L);
        assert((long)something.get(KEYS.SOMETHING_ID) == 1L);

        something.set(KEYS.SOMETHING_ID, 2L);
        assert((long)something.get(KEYS.ID) == 2L);

        something.set(KEYS.TITLE, "Dr. Strangelove");
        assert(something.get(KEYS.NAME).equals("Dr. Strangelove"));
        assert(something.get(KEYS.DESCRIPTION).equals("Dr. Strangelove"));
    }
}
```